# How to convert between C++ ArrayFire and C++ Eigen matrices?

Tags: c++, eigen, arrayfire

I am new to Eigen and looking to learn ArrayFire for GPU acceleration. I would like to implement ArrayFire within my existing Eigen code rather than having to re-code all of my functions.

Is there a way to convert from an ArrayFire matrix to an Eigen matrix, and vice-versa?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Just from a quick look at the documentation, [there is an ArrayFire array constructor taking host data in exactly the format Eigen uses for storage](https://arrayfire.org/docs/classaf_1_1array.htm#a1144078b1596e7d29f57b1a0a1c9b1a8) and a [copy method that presumably does the inverse operation](https://arrayfire.org/docs/classaf_1_1array.htm#a5cc0f3c2307de6b82ede47c9b26da2d0)

Comment: hey @Homer512, sorry still new to all this. So can I just do "array AF_array(dims, eigen_array)", where dims has dimension info and eigen_array is the eigen array and then I will get an ArrayFire array called AF_array?

Answer (score 2):

Untested since I'm just looking at the ArrayFire documentation.

1. Copy Eigen matrix into a new AF array [using this constructor](https://arrayfire.org/docs/classaf_1_1array.htm#aa2ebe6a7b991fbe6231321138e79121c):

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf hostside = ...;
af::array deviceside(hostside.rows(), hostside.cols(), hostside.data());
```

It's important that a plain matrix or 2D array is used on Eigen's side (not an `Eigen::Ref` or other type of sub-matrix block) since neither the constructor nor any of the copy functions accept a column stride.

2. [Copy host data](https://arrayfire.org/docs/classaf_1_1array.htm#aa70b253da2d32394c521a815f7627116) into an existing device-side array

```cpp
deviceside.write(hostside.data(), hostside.size() * sizeof(float));
```

3. [Copy device-side data](https://arrayfire.org/docs/classaf_1_1array.htm#a5cc0f3c2307de6b82ede47c9b26da2d0) into an Eigen matrix

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf hostside(deviceside.dims(0), deviceside.dims(1));
deviceside.host(hostside.data());
```

Comment: Thanks i'm just trying to get my head around this code. Is this all for going from Eigen matrix to AF array, or both ways? Also, would just using for-loops for map each element from one array type to the other be less computationally efficient?

Comment: @E_1996 when dealing with GPUs it is common to refer to "host-side" as stuff on the CPU and in CPU main memory while "device-side" refers to the GPU and its memory. So the first two points of the answer copy from Eigen to AF. The last does the inverse, copying results back to the CPU main memory

Comment: @E_1996 And yes, going item by item would be extremely expensive unless AF has some form of mechanism making it faster. Even then, scalar access is slower than memcpy, so it would still be pretty slow

Comment: I see, thanks for all the info  - I didnt know about the host-side and device-side stuff referring to CPU/GPU so this makes a lot more sense now. Good to know that item-by-item is more expensive so I don't waste time attempting that.